# When I try to handle missing values in pandas, some methods are not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan, missing-data

I am trying to handle some missing values in a dataset. This is the [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-missing-data-in-pandas/) for the tutorial that I am using to learn. Below is the code that I am using to read the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

questions = pd.read_csv("./archive/questions.csv")

print(questions.head())
```

This is what my data looks like

[image]

These are the methods that I am using to handle the missing values. None of them are working.

```
questions.replace(to_replace = np.nan, value = -99)
questions = questions.fillna(method ='pad')
questions.interpolate(method ='linear', limit_direction = 'forward')
```

Then I tried to drop the rows with the missing values. None of them are working either. All of them are returning Empty dataframe.

```
questions.dropna()
questions.dropna(how = "all")
questions.dropna(axis = 1)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Edit:

Values from `questions.head()`

```
[[1 '2008-07-31T21:26:37Z' nan '2011-03-28T00:53:47Z' 1 nan 0.0]
 [4 '2008-07-31T21:42:52Z' nan nan 458 8.0 13.0]
 [6 '2008-07-31T22:08:08Z' nan nan 207 9.0 5.0]
 [8 '2008-07-31T23:33:19Z' '2013-06-03T04:00:25Z' '2015-02-11T08:26:40Z'
  42 nan 8.0]
 [9 '2008-07-31T23:40:59Z' nan nan 1410 1.0 58.0]]
```

Values from `questions.head()` in a dictionary form.

```
{'Id': {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 6, 3: 8, 4: 9}, 'CreationDate': {0: '2008-07-31T21:26:37Z', 1: '2008-07-31T21:42:52Z', 2: '2008-07-31T22:08:08Z', 3: '2008-07-31T23:33:19Z', 4: '2008-07-31T23:40:59Z'}, 'ClosedDate': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: '2013-06-03T04:00:25Z', 4: nan}, 'DeletionDate': {0: '2011-03-28T00:53:47Z', 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: '2015-02-11T08:26:40Z', 4: nan}, 'Score': {0: 1, 1: 458, 2: 207, 3: 42, 4: 1410}, 'OwnerUserId': {0: nan, 1: 8.0, 2: 9.0, 3: nan, 4: 1.0}, 'AnswerCount': {0: 0.0, 1: 13.0, 2: 5.0, 3: 8.0, 4: 58.0}}
```

Information regarding the dataset

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 17203824 entries, 0 to 17203823
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column        Dtype  
---  ------        -----  
 0   Id            int64  
 1   CreationDate  object 
 2   ClosedDate    object 
 3   DeletionDate  object 
 4   Score         int64  
 5   OwnerUserId   float64
 6   AnswerCount   float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(2), object(3)
memory usage: 918.8+ MB
```

Comment: Could it be that 'NaN' is actually a string? Try questions.replace('NaN','')

Comment: Tried it. Not working.

Comment: can you post `questions.head().values`

Comment: I did. It is right after "This is what my data looks like".

Comment: erm unless I am going blind here -  can you post questions.head().`values`? Also, avoid using `img` as outputs but rather use code (it makes everything much easier)

Comment: I have posted the values.

Comment: can you do `questions.head().to_dict()` as well as `questions.info()`. Something doesn't look right with your data. Also, the link you've provided for the csv file doesn't have the file. Can you replace the img with an actual data from `questions.head()`

Comment: I did. Can you please check?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to specify the `axis` explicitly and see if it will work? The other fillna() should still work without axis, but for pad you need it so it knows how to fill the missing values.

```
>>> questions.fillna(method='pad', axis=1)
  Id          CreationDate            ClosedDate          DeletionDate Score OwnerUserId AnswerCount
0  1  2008-07-31T21:26:37Z  2008-07-31T21:26:37Z  2011-03-28T00:53:47Z     1           1           0
1  4  2008-07-31T21:42:52Z  2008-07-31T21:42:52Z  2008-07-31T21:42:52Z   458           8          13
2  6  2008-07-31T22:08:08Z  2008-07-31T22:08:08Z  2008-07-31T22:08:08Z   207           9           5
3  8  2008-07-31T23:33:19Z  2013-06-03T04:00:25Z  2015-02-11T08:26:40Z    42          42           8
4  9  2008-07-31T23:40:59Z  2008-07-31T23:40:59Z  2008-07-31T23:40:59Z  1410           1          58
```

just `fillna()` applied on entire DataFrame works as expected.

```
>>> questions.fillna('-')

   Id          CreationDate            ClosedDate          DeletionDate  Score OwnerUserId  AnswerCount
0   1  2008-07-31T21:26:37Z                     -  2011-03-28T00:53:47Z      1           -          0.0
1   4  2008-07-31T21:42:52Z                     -                     -    458           8         13.0
2   6  2008-07-31T22:08:08Z                     -                     -    207           9          5.0
3   8  2008-07-31T23:33:19Z  2013-06-03T04:00:25Z  2015-02-11T08:26:40Z     42           -          8.0
4   9  2008-07-31T23:40:59Z                     -                     -   1410           1         58.0
```

Comment: What about the other ones?